# Why doesn't $P!{} works correctly on JasperServer?

Tags: sql, parameters, jasperserver

In Jasper Studio, i created new Jasper Report with SQL srcript

```
select * from
(
SELECT 1 v from dual union all 
SELECT 5 v from dual union all 
SELECT 4 v from dual union all
SELECT 2 v from dual union all
SELECT 3 v from dual
) da
$P!{P_C}
```

there are two Parameters:

```
    <parameter name="P_P" class="java.lang.Boolean"/>
    <parameter name="P_C" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[IF($P{P_P},"where da.v =1","")]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
```

When i run this report in Jasper Studio then everything is works fine and result is as expected:

```
_________
TEST REP|
________|
V       |
________|
1       |
2       |
3       |
4       |
5       |
```

But on JasperServer i get an error:

```
There was an error on the server. Try again or contact site administrators. (Error UID: 16864f27-a17a-43d1-8ed6-4386b52f57a0)
```

If i delete `$P!{P_C}` from SQL script, every thing works fine.

If there is anybody who has the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

You will be able to troubleshoot way easier if you get your user/role permisson to see those error's stack traces by editing the .../WEB-INF/applicationContext-security.xml file if you can.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the log file to see the error returned.
"C:\Jaspersoft\jasperreports-server-cp-7.5.0\apache-tomcat\webapps\jasperserver\WEB-INF\logs\jasperserver.log"